# How to specify fixed width for all columns in table with ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, flexbox, material-ui

I am retrieving some data where the number of entities is variable and are displayed as columns in my table. I wish to have fixed widths for all the columns. But when I try to do this, I find that the widths are not obeyed, and each column is stretched as per available total space.

Example sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sid-ceugx?file=/src/App.js

But just by removing the column width on a single table, I am able to get all the other columns to obey their widths, and only this one column now keeps stretching.

Example sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-flower-wuq2b?file=/src/App.js

How can I enforce widths on all the columns, and not have the table stretch the entire width? Do note that I would like to avoid specifying total table width as this is variable based on the data being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this. Set `style={{ width: "auto", tableLayout: "auto"}` on the 'Table' tag.

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-surf-vb4ts?file=/src/App.js